# How to change the format of values of a matrix in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

```
[[0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.6534920e+05 1.3689780e+05
  4.7178410e+05]
 [1.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 1.6259770e+05 1.5137759e+05
  4.4389853e+05]
 [0.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 1.5344151e+05 1.0114555e+05
  4.0793454e+05]
 [0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.4437241e+05 1.1867185e+05
  3.8319962e+05]
 [1.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 1.1698380e+05
  4.5173060e+04]]
```

How should I change the values of the matrix so that the are rounded off in the format %0f?

Comment: How do you print this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [numpy's vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) function and pass a function to be applied on a list:

```
import numpy as np
rfunc = np.vectorize(round)     # round() is a python function which rounds inputs to a precision set by number of decimals; e.g: np.round(2.3456, 1) returns 2.3 
rfunc(a, 2)     # 2 is the precision which needs to be adjusted
```

[image]